# script src tag loading index.jsp itself

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am trying to load js files from index.jsp using script tag with src attribute. If I load them from external url they are loading fine, but if I try to load locally (for example grommet in below code) it shows that it has loaded. But when I check the response in developer tools of chrome the content is same as index.jsp and original grommet.js content is missing.

Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='/grommet/css/grommet.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  <script src="/grommet/grommet.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Actual output

Response body for grommet.min.js has

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400italic,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='/grommet/css/grommet.min.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.1/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  <script src="/grommet/grommet.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Expected output

Should be same as grommet.min.js library (http://grommet.io/assets/latest/grommet.min.js)

If I change
 to
http://grommet.io/assets/latest/grommet.min.js everything works fine.

Console.log shows this error on line number 1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

This error appears only if I add script src="/grommet/grommet.min.js" otherwise this error is gone

Comment: Can you include the actual output and the expected output?

Comment: when u view the content of the gormmet.min.js where is the url pointing?...is it pointing to index.jsp?

Comment: When I view the content of grommet.min.js then request url points to https://example.com/grommet/grommet.min.js but response body is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. There was a check that until you are logged in scripts will not be loaded. I bypassed that check to load this particular script and it worked